# Know the name of the application that is in foreground - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch

I understand that your application is sandboxed in Apple environment. But I have a need to know the application that user currently is playing with - just the name is enough in my application which is currently in background.

Is there any possibility to know the application name which is currently in foreground?

Please do not down vote. My intention is to check if somebody has used some private API in the past to do this.

Comment: I do not believe this can be done without jail breaking. As you said yourself, apps are sandboxed.

Comment: The only app is in foreground is your app when you run, all other are in background, so when you open your app to see which app is in foreground you get yours, if it is possible to determine. Another fact it is not possible to determine, or access any other application in iOS.

Comment: I understand. Point here is to check if there is a way for my app (while being in background) to know what is the current foreground app.

Comment: Not without jailbreak (private API).

Comment: ok. I shall keep this thread open for few more hours for few more opinions and then shall close it. May be one of you can put your opinion as an answer and I shall accept that.